# Prevent JPanel repeatedly adding ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am creating a chess game on my free time, and after the users performs an action (ie moves a piece), I update the window(JFrame) to display the new piece position. However, in my update function, I am using the add(Component) function to add the JLabels to a JPanel. Therefore, every time there is an update multiple JLabels are being added to the component because the add() function stacks JLabels.

```
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(theTiles.get(i).getPiece().getImagePath()));
    }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(icon);

    //Here is where the error is:
    theTiles.get(i).add(label);
    label.repaint();

    this.window.validate();
    this.window.repaint();
```

Because this function is called whenever there is an update, "theTiles.get(i).add(label)" is adding multiple JLabels to the JPanel each time it is called. I have tried to set a unique JLabel as a private variable of the class so that it just replaces that JLabel instead of adding more when it needs to update for example:

```
public class TilePanel extends JPanel{
    //JLabel variable
    private JLabel someLabel = new JLabel();

    TilePanel(){
    //Add the component to the Panel
         this.add(someLabel);
   }

    public Jlabel setLabel(JPanel newLabel){
    //setLabel function to use in the "update" function
        this.someLabel = newLabel
    }


...
//Use setLabel instead of add(Component)
theTiles.get(i).setLabel(label);
```

However, doing this causes no image to appear. Where am I going wrong?
(Note: This is my first time working with GUIs)

Comment: You've changed the reference (to someLabel), but the original label is still on the screen (and I'm not sure how that would compile), when changing the label, you need to remove the old component and then add the new one

Comment: You could also just change the icon of the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MadProgrammer for the tips; here is the solution that I found:

In my update function I just call:

```
theTiles.get(i).setImage();
```

and In my class I have the following:

```
public class TilePanel extends JPanel{
    //A JLabel for each tile
    private JLabel theLabel = new JLabel();

TilePanel(int i, int j){
        //constructor add the Label to itself
        this.add(theLabel);


//A function to "setIcon" instead of using .add() multiple times
public void setImage(){
    //assign in an icon
    if (this.pieceAtTile != null){
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try{
                img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(this.pieceAtTile.getImagePath()));
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            this.theLabel.setIcon(icon);
        }
        else{this.theLabel.setIcon(null);}
    theLabel.repaint();
    }
```